# Using M1 iPad Pro (2020) to charge other USB-C devices

Tags: ipad, usb, charging

Is it possible to charge use an M1 iPad Pro (2020) as USB-C battery pack in a pinch? For example, would it be possible to plug in a MacBook (or any device that accepts USB-C charging) and have the iPad charge the other device?
[https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT209186#:~:text=Use%20your%20iPad%20to%20charge%20other%20devices](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT209186#:%7E:text=Use%20your%20iPad%20to%20charge%20other%20devices) seems to suggest this only works for a subset of devices e.g. USB-C->Lightning, or iPad to iPad.
Some additional Google suggests that USB OTG (On The Go) support is required, and Google suggests that the M1 iPad Pro (2020) does not support this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - the iPad does not provide charging power, just accessory level power.

I like [Anker PD devices](https://us.anker.com/products/a1268), but you have a ton of options in that space without needing a computer attached to the battery. The [Anker 9 series offer more current / faster charge](https://us.anker.com/products/b1284) for double the price of the previous unit.

Comment: Thanks @bmike for the suggestions! I was initially hoping to reduce the amount of stuff I carry in my backpack by having my iPad be my emergency charger for my phone/laptop in a pinch, but I'll start looking into the battery space to see what's available!

Comment: FYI to later readers: @MacGuffin's answer worked for me; with USB-A cable, successfully charged android phone from ipad.

Comment: Thanks @Daryn I need to retest and edit this.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible to use an iPad Pro to charge other USB-C devices.  The USB-C port on iPad Pro tablets can provide up to 7.5 watts.  I recalled reading this somewhere, it just took a minute to find a source to prove I wasn't making this up: https://9to5mac.com/2018/11/07/ipad-pro-usb-c-accessories/

Plugging a USB-C to USB-C cable from an iPad Pro tablet to another device can mean the power could flow in a direction opposite to what you want.  USB-C allows power flow in either direction and which way it flows can be random.  If power is not flowing the direction you want then usually disconnecting and reconnecting will reverse the flow.  That doesn't always work though because it depends on the other device too.

A way to know the power flows the direction you want is to put a USB-C to USB-A (female) adapter on the iPad then plug a USB-C to USB-A (male) cable into that and the cable into the device you want to charge.  USB-A ports only allow power to flow out and use of an adapter will force the direction of power flow.  You can also flip this around to charge your iPad Pro from a phone or whatever.  Because there is USB-A in the middle the maximum power flow will be limited by that USB-A connector, which is 5 volts at 2.4 amps, or 12 watts.

7.5 watts is the maximum power from an iPad Pro USB-C port, whatever device you connect might not draw the maximum power for many different reasons. Again, if you use a USB-C to USB-A adapter and a USB-A to USB-C cable to connect a USB-C device to something else for power the power flow will be limited to 12 watts or less because of the USB-A port in the middle, no matter how much power the source is rated to supply.  If you want 20 watts into your iPad Pro from a 20 watt USB-C power brick then you need to use a proper USB-C to USB-C cable.

Could you run your MacBook from your iPad Pro?  That depends a lot on the model of MacBook.  One clue will be what size of power adapter came with your MacBook.  The power adpater included with the MacBook will give an idea on how much power the laptop consumes, and how big the battery is compared to the iPad Pro.  A MacBook that came with a 29 watt power adapter is going to take less power than a MacBook that came with a 140 watt power adapter.

I'm keeping in mind the provision "in a pinch".  This is something you might not want to do regularly as this will introduce additional wear on the iPad Pro battery.  Consider the size of the battery in the iPad Pro versus the device you are trying to charge.  A Macbook will have a larger battery (perhaps MUCH larger battery) and so you might not get a useful amount of energy from the iPad Pro.  Compared to an iPhone though the iPad Pro will have much more energy and so could extend the iPhone use considerably.

Comment: Confirmed, I was able to charge android phone from ipad pro. Thanks and extra star to @MacGuffin for suggesting USB-A cable (plus C-to-A adaptor). With USB C-to-C cable, no charging happened for me, but USB-A cable solved it. Note: charging stopped when iPad screen goes off. Change iPad's Auto-lock setting to make it stay awake longer if not using the iPad.